# Best setup for secure entreprise file storage?

Tags: backup, cloud, network-attached-storage

I'm looking for a solution to store files such as PDFs, .docs, images and videos for entreprise purposes. We're a startup with 15 people who need to access those files in sync all the time. Sometimes from abroad. The solution must incorporate permissions management and if possible encryption. The more secure the better. We also want to be able to backup the data. All for less than 100$ per month.

Which infrastructure would you advice ?

Edit : I edited the question for clarity, by SMB i didn't meant Server Message Block, i meant Small and Midsize Businesses.

Edit 2 : I think i'm going to go with Amazon S3 and expandrive as a client for employees access to files.

Comment: Related: [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/q/384686/58408)

Answer (score 3):

What about Sharepoint? For the Enterprise price, it comes with required functionality for business (Outlook, Word, Excel etc.). Check [this](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans).

In case you consider to buy SMB boxes, I can suggest checking Synology, QNAP options. For NAS storage I use Synology.

As for backups, buy two boxes. First box run SMB share. Use the second one to store backups. Veeam, Acronis, Symantec are backup software I can suggest to go with to implement a backup plan. For sure, consider [3-2-1 rule](https://knowledgebase.starwindsoftware.com/explanation/the-3-2-1-backup-rule/) and RTO&RPO.

Comment: We have a not so great internet connexion http://beta.speedtest.net/result/5975433240 so if we chose Synology it's going to be hard to access files from abroad

Answer (score 1):

If you will opt for cloud storage, you need to think about encrypt your data before to send it.

I mean that you have to use **Cryptomator** or others solutions that create a container where you can store your files "safely".

Comment: The current setup contains a Synology NAS which i plan to sync with the cloud for internet access. Syno encrypts data with his own algorithm. However i don't know how i will access that data on the cloud now since it's encrypted...

Comment: If you will have an access to your encrypted files through your cloud provider, you need to use **Synology Cloud Sync Decryption Tool**.

Comment: Do you think it can be used by employees seamlessly by non-tech employees ?

Comment: Keep it mind employees can't download on their disk, the whole 1TB of data, they access it throught the cloud, would the tool work on these conditions ? Also, it's a tool to decrypt 'Cloud sync encryption' however, we already encrypt the data on the Synology NAS before it gets transfered to the cloud, i fear these are two different encryption features.

Comment: Generally, your provider provides a multi-platform client with these possibilities : all folders sync or folder selective sync.
So, your employees will not need to sync all data on their laptop. And once sync done, they use Synology software to decrypt data with private key.
The software is pretty easy-to-use, you will need just less 5 minutes to show how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Security and cloud storage is quite oxymoron - your data are not secure if someone out of your company has access to machine with your data. If security is important for you buy some two servers (because of high availability) and use some VPN for accessing from remote locations.

Comment: Company data will be stored in a guarded data center facilty behind a powerfull security infrastructure composed of a 24/24 7/7 IT security team. And all that will still being accessible with great performance. It would be quiet presumptous to think i would do a better security job than one of the biggest tech companies in the world with a 100$ per month budget. And even if i was the the super paranoid type guy who thinks NSA wants to steal small businesses data, i don't think any regular security setup would protect me from undisclosed backdoors and 0days.